# How can I get a Grails UUID of n digests in a domain-class?

Tags: grails

I am new in Grails and want to have a id column as uuid with n digests. Like:

```
class Book {
   String id
}
```

How do I get that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
class Book {

  String id

  static constraints = {
    id maxSize: 18
  }

  static mapping = {
    id generator:'assigned'
  }

def beforeValidate() {
    if (!id) {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1")
        byte[] digest  = sha1.digest(uuid.getBytes())
        def tmpId = new  BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16)
        id = tmpId[0..n]    // size of the id
    }
}

}
```

where n is the number of digests.